# when webm extracts aac, the duration is inconsistent

Tags: google-chrome-extension, ffmpeg, aac, webm, web-mediarecorder

When I try to extract aac from `webm`, there will be inconsistencies in duration. `aac` is ten minutes less. Different `webm` videos, the gap is not the same.

`webm` video is generated by `chrome extension` [chrome.tabCapture.capture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture#method-capture)

code:

```
chrome.tabCapture.capture({
  video: true,
  audio: true,
  videoConstraints: {
    mandatory: {
      minWidth: 1920,
      minHeight: 1080,
      maxWidth: 1920,
      maxHeight: 1080,
      maxFrameRate: 30,
      minFrameRate: 30,
    }
  }
})
```

The above code will return a stream, I will use JS's [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/MediaRecorder) method to process this stream, and finally save it as a webm file.

code:

```
new MediaRecorder(stream, {
  audioBitsPerSecond: 128000,
  videoBitsPerSecond: 2500000,
  mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'
})
```

If you don't know the meaning of the above code, it doesn't matter, I will explain the main information:

1. width: `1920`
2. height: `1080`
3. FPS: `30`
4. audioBits: `128000`
5. videoBits: `2500000`
6. mimeType: `video/webm;codecs=vp9`

I tried a lot of methods, like the following:

```sh
# 1
ffmpeg -i ./source.webm -y -fflags +genpts -max_muxing_queue_size 99999 -r 15 -crf 30 -filter:v crop=750:560:0:0 ./x.mp4
ffmpeg -i ./x.mp4 -y -vn -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 200k ./x.aac

# 2
ffmpeg -i ./source.webm -y -vn -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 200k ./x.aac

# 3
ffmpeg -i ./source.webm -y -vn -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 200k -map 0 ./x.aac

# 4
ffmpeg -i ./source.webm -y -max_muxing_queue_size 99999 -r 15 -crf 30 -filter:v crop=750:560:0:0 ./x.mp4
ffmpeg -i ./source.webm -y -vn -acodec aac -b:a 200k ./x.aac

# etc.
```

But without exception, all failed. I have been plagued by this problem for 4 days.

webm file download url: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m4fC1hU-tXFPOZayrYCs-yteSTxw_TaW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome which you can report on https://crbug.com.

Comment: You can't extract the raw bitstream out of the container and expect timestamps to remain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What many conferencing or web recording apps do, is not store silence when audio input is missing or silent (as defined by some volume threshold). WebM and MP4 are time-indexed containers and so the media data has the correct timestamps for playback or editing purposes. `.mp3` or `.aac` don't, so without timestamps, the duration is that of the actual amount of audio recorded and stored. An additional issue is that the duration you see with `ffmpeg -i in.aac` is an estimate based on the file size and the notional bitrate. For a VBR stream, this estimate can be wrong.

Either store and work with the audio in a container with timestamps, like MP4, MKV..etc

```
ffmpeg -i ./x.mp4 -y -vn -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 200k ./x.mp4
```

or plug in the timestamp gaps with audio silence,

```
ffmpeg -i ./x.mp4 -y -vn -af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0:min_hard_comp=0.01 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 200k ./x.aac
```

This latter command may still show the wrong estimated duration but an editor, after generating peaks, will show the correct duration.

Comment: you saved me.. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have tested and found that the first one has no effect, and the second one has no problem.

Comment: When I used the second method to extract aac, there was no problem with the duration. But the sound inside will be intermittent. This is another aac file I extracted: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W9QW_NHN-CXJ5CWV9edQL3LNbwdFv5Ga/view?usp=sharing (Starting from 5 minutes and 14 seconds)

Comment: Ok, I looked at source.webm and the audio stream is fine but the timestamps for both audio and video are wrong. Video playback happens faster than realtime. ffmpeg also complains about file metadata: `Length 5 indicated by an EBML number's first byte 0x0c at pos 15688587 (0xef638b) exceeds max length 4` and `Invalid length 0x149d > 0x8 for element with ID 0xE7 at 0x1872992`

Comment: Is there any way to solve this problem? Because the sound now has a noticeable intermittent feeling

Comment: Audio timestamp gaps shouldn't be filled in (what my 2nd command does) because the timestamps are wrong. The video needs to be corrected. I'll look at it later today.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. If you need any additional information from me, I will provide it immediately.

Comment: The video duration as per the overlaid running clock looks correct. But the playback is too fast. I'd consider this a bug with the plugin and should be corrected there.

Comment: Well, thank you very much. In other words, FFmpeg can't solve this problem?

Comment: If the pattern of timestamp/timescale distortion was known, it could be corrected. Raise an issue with the extension author.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I have solved the problem of webm audio and video misplacement. Currently, the second method can be used for alignment without any other side effects. The misalignment of webm audio and video is caused by recording multiple at the same time.

Comment: @Gyan 
The 2. method is also working for my cause, but I also got a lot of clipping. Even at the undamaged parts of my video. Thx a lot anyway!
My Thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64606142/ffmpeg-extract-audio-with-exact-timing-despite-corrupted-intermediate-audio-ch

Comment: Change `async=1` to `async=3072`