# FFMPEG : Extract Audio with exact Timing despite corrupted intermediate audio chunks

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have a full automated tool chain which first concatenate video chunks and adjusts user events to it.
This first step uses 3rd party software, I am not able to fix the problem there.
Later in the process I extract the audio from the video. Sometimes there are corrupted audio chunks inbetween. FFMPEG ignores the corrupted parts on extraction. So I got a mutch shorter audio (the linked events rely on the exact length of the org A/V). It wouldnt be a big issue if it would only happen at the end, I know how to pad it there, but at random poistions, I didnt find an option at the documentation doing the job.
The only solution that worked was (pretty dirty I know) to convert the video to another video container with removed video stream and rename the file to MP3/AAC. It was working at windows/Android but all Mac-Browser didnt play it.

The -filter_complex -discard looks promising but I didnt find any good example for the correct syntax.
I have found an Adobe Tool doing the job correctly so I hope there is a way to do with ffmpeg, too.

```
General
Complete name                  : C:\tmp123\video.mp4
Format                         : MPEG-4
Format profile                 : Base Media
Codec ID                       : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                      : 57.8 MiB
Duration                       : 6 min 51 s
Overall bit rate               : 1 177 kb/s
Writing application            : Lavf58.26.100

Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AVC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                 : Baseline@L4
Format settings, CABAC         : No
Format settings, RefFrames     : 2 frames
Format settings, GOP           : M=1, N=30
Codec ID                       : avc1
Codec ID/Info                  : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                       : 6 min 51 s
Bit rate                       : 1 003 kb/s
Width                          : 1 920 pixels
Height                         : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 16:9
Frame rate mode                : Constant
Frame rate                     : 30.303 FPS
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Scan type                      : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.016
Stream size                    : 49.2 MiB (85%)

Audio
ID                             : 2
Format                         : AAC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                 : LC
Codec ID                       : 40
Duration                       : 6 min 51 s
Bit rate mode                  : Constant
Bit rate                       : 168 kb/s
Channel(s)                     : 2 channels
Channel positions              : Front: L R
Sampling rate                  : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                     : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode               : Lossy
Stream size                    : 8.22 MiB (14%)
Default                        : Yes
Alternate group                : 1
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57198419/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Gyan I was able to fix the missing time by:

```
ffmpeg -i x.mp4 -y -vn -af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0:min_hard_comp=0.01 -acodec libfdk_aac x.aac
```

But I had a lot of audio clipping. Gyan suggest to use "async=3072" instead, but it was not working for me. The clipping was still present. I played around with the other values and min_hard_comp did the job. After setting it to 0.2 instead of 0.01 the clipping was gone. The generated audio does not fit 100% now, but it was redused from >1:30min to 30ms for a 6:51min video:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -y -vn -af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0:min_hard_comp=0.2  audioout1.mp3
```

Thx Gyan!